# using Composite Pattern to count the number of people in the world

Tags: design-patterns, uml, diagram, composite

I'm trying to make a Composite Pattern that counts the number of people in the world, the continent, the state... sorry no state but country my bad sorry

Here is the pattern that I follow:[image]

I did this:

[image]

but I am not sure it's right, because can I use `leaf -> population` ?

Because when I did Composite Pattern for PC so its (PC= component from PC will be Cabinet = composite, from Cabinet will be HDD= leaf and Motherboard = composite, from Motherboard will be RAM = leaf and CPU = leaf). What I want to say every leafs are different and in my diagram are same.

and you think I have something good at least.

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Your Generalizations (Inheritances) are totally wrong. Goal of subclasses is to **extend parent class functionality**. Maybe `Area` instead of the `World` at the top. Also `State` is not **kind of** `Continent` and so on.

Comment: you shouldnt start with the leaf, when doing it so you shall start with world->population

Comment: I dont know how your PC composite looks like, but how you described it looks also not good. Your can start with a class like device, that can contain further devices, and each device can consist of circuits, mechanics, .... So you have your device PC, that consists of the devices HDD, BlueRay, Mainboard, Powersupply. And each of these devices can contain further devices or curciuts....

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should start with an analysis of your problem. So what is that you have and how is it related. So you have a **World** that *consists* of **continents**, where each continent *consists* of **countries**, where each country *consists* of **regions**. When doing such a OO Analysis, the nouns (here marked  in bold) are candidates for your classes. And the relational terms give some indications howp the classes are related (marked italic).

So what can we see frmo this? There are some terms (called entities) that have some directly ordered hierarchical containment relations. But no relation in the kind that something can be seen as an element of the other type. This is an important information when thinking about how to inherit from each other; as the inherits relation can be seen a specialization, it doesnt make any sense here: a country is not a specific world and a world is not a specific country. Further, we see there are no bypasses, e.g. a contry is no direct part of the world. And no element can contain an element of its own type, e.g. no country contains a country.

[image]

So what can we learn from this brief analysis? We cannot formulate the problem as a composite without changing significant expressiveness (e.g. changing the intended hierarchy) or without introducing much additional complexity (e.g. by constraints).

And now in the second step, we develop a design out of the analysis results. How the design looks like at the end depends on what shall be done with the elements.

1. Solution: In your example you can just add a calculatePopulation operation to any of the classes. As any class knows its parts and their types, this can directly be done by calling the calculatePopulation operation of the contained instances of the next element type. This would be the OO way in solving such problems, which is most likely the best way if there are no further constraints.

[image]

And to start it you just call calculatePopulation of your wold instance.

If you want to treat any kind of element in a unified way, you can create an abstract class or interface and let all the elements inherit from it/implement it. This class/interface declares the calculatePopulation operation. Whith that improved solution you can start with an arbitrary element of your hierarchy to calculate the population without  taking care for what kind of element it is.

2. Solution: When you want to have an algorithm that is not implemented inside of the class hierarchy and that is recursive. In that case you need an abstraction, such that you can handle all the elements in the same way, as the algorithm implementation shall not take care for too much of the details. Thus also let all the elements inherit from an abstact class that has an operation that provides the contained elements and an operation that provides the population, which is directly part of the element  ( not transitive/indirectly as in the case before). So now you would have the situation that you have two clearly disticitve cases, first you have child element and no direct population and, second, you have no child elements and a direct population. But your traversal can ignore this.

[image]

Here you start it by calling your implementation (which is an other class) and passing the object of which you want to have to population.

There are further solutions, of course. But all of those using a composite just for this problem are very artificial, because it is by its concept recursive and your problem is not recursive (i.e. there is no element that can contain a element of the same type) and thus the composite is unsiateble or lets call it oversized.

Comment: I gave also some comments to the other answers.

Answer (score -2):

At least you do not need to have World, Continent, State, Region.

Only Composite with maybe a property type is needed to know if this is a Continent or a State or a Region.

State should be the leaf no ?

Think like an files tree: the number of levels is not defined, the pattern supports any depth number.

On State you get a method getPopulation which is defined also in Component as abstract and in Composite with a return -1 or infinite (a value meaning not implemented).

For me, the method getChild is needed on leaf and Component also. Without it, it is not possible to implement a recursive algorithm to navigate through the composite.

On leaf, it returns an empty list: this the way to know that a leaf is reached.

[image]

PS : I leave the aggregation because it is used in your first diagram, if i do it i would use a simple association or a composition but not an aggreation.

Comment: And what is state i know I wrote state but i mean country so what another leaf can I use ?

Comment: @Dolis no just change State by Country if you need Country as leaf only. If you need State and Country as leaf, change State by Leaf (or a more meaning full word) and add a property type with possible values State or Country (like for Composite)

Comment: I guess you need a constraint. Otherwise you can make a `State` of `Worlds`. Theoretically this is possible. But the real world does not allow that.

Comment: @kilian are you sure ? It depends of the enumeration used for Composite and the one used for the leaf, id State no ?

Comment: No. As you constructed it you can mix World/Continent/Region at wish. That will give a mash-up. However, if you add a simple constraint (plain text will do) you can describe that a hierarchical use is needed (and I'd change my down to an up vote too).

Comment: The proposedsolution is not that good, because you need now many case distinctions based on the assigned enum. Which can easily be omit by using different classes. By using two different typing concepts, first have state as class and all other elments as a generic type using an enum, makes it even worse.

Comment: @sim I'd say it depends. It's an alternative to the OP's model. Sometimes you want to reduce the number of different classes. That's where you can use the enum. The OP's model is a better choice if you'r doing other things with `World/..`. than just counting.

Comment: @Kilian i agree about mixing World/Continent/Region, but in your comment you said "Otherwise you can make a State of Worlds" that was not possible. And after i prefer to use enum than to create empty classes or classes quite similar just to define a type ...