# Constant storing c++?

Tags: c++, storage

I'm trying to store several constants somewhere in my cpp project. Looking around a little bit, the way to do it seems to be defining the variable in the .h file and declaring it in .cpp file.

```
//.h
class Region {
public:
   static const int CC;
};
//.cpp
const int Region::CC= 12;
```

I've learned  that to solve the static in-class definition error, you can use `constexpr`.

What I need to store are regions (think coordinates/rectangles), basically 2 coordinates in a coordinate-system. I would like to be able to classify and use a region but also use its subregions.

Pseudocode example;

```
Country(100, 100, 900, 900){
    City(150, 150, 200, 200) {
        House1(155, 155, 160, 160)
        House2(170, 170, 180, 180)
    }
    Lake(300, 300, 400, 400)
}
```

Where regions could be stacked "indefinitely" (lets say max 10 nested). Where I could access its regions like so;

```
Country //returns 100,100,900,900
Country.City //returns 150,150,200,200
Country.City.House1 //returns 155,155,160,160
Country.Lake //returns 300,300,400,400
```

**How would I create a structure that allows this kind of storage/accessing?** I was thinking maybe namespaces but the problem arise that just the namespace should also store coordinates.

Comment: Something like `struct S {std::string name; int x, y, w, h; std::vector<S> subregions;};`?

Comment: What is the problem? It doesn't seem particularly clear what you're asking.

Comment: aside: static const primitives can have their values in the header.

Comment: It looks to me like static const variables aren't what you want for this.  It means you will be stuck with one country, with one city, with one house.  Sure, you could have a House1, and a House2, but that's very poor design as when you get to House1000 you'll be quite fed up.

Answer (score 1):

Your example has two aspects, one is the structure and one is the location of the elements in the structure. It seems that you only identified the second aspect properly. You try to define both in a somehow constant way, what is not a good idea, although the information is constant :-)

```
    struct GeoPosition
    {
       int  a,b,c,d;
    }

class GeoLocatedElement
{
protected:
   GeoPosition location;
public:
   GeoLocatedElement(GeoLocation loc);
}

class Region:public GeoLocatedElement
{
...
}

..
```

A good solution would be having a super class, e.g., GeoPositionedElement, that has an instance variable of geoposition struct (NOT constant!!!). The constructructor of your superclass acceppts such a geolocation instance and stores the information into its local member.

And further you have subclasses for each kind of sub-element you need, like region, city, house, lake, etc. Additionally, each subclass has a member for contained elements. If you want to restrict this, then define it accordingsly otherwise allow to add GeoPositionedElements. See here a similar example on how to do this: [using Composite Pattern to count the number of people in the world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173736/using-composite-pattern-to-count-the-number-of-people-in-the-world/48179353#48179353).

And finally, you need to set it up by creating the instances of your structural elements and when doing so, call their constructor with the geopositions. You can store the geopositions in similar way as you have shown, but in arrays. A better way would be to provide the information through a file, e.g., CSV or JSON, and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way would be to just simply build a struct with all of the relevant info you need, and build an array of that type to hold how ever many "countries" you want.

struct Country{
.
.
.
};

and just put into it all the sub categories you want in it.